# hadoop3 can not create timeline server hbase table

Tags: hadoop3

I read the Hadoop 3 about the timeline server v.2 document, it says

Finally, run the schema creator tool to create the necessary tables:

> bin/hadoop
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.timelineservice.storage.TimelineSchemaCreator
>   -create

The TimelineSchemaCreator tool supports a few options that may come handy especially when you are testing. For example, you can use -skipExistingTable (-s for short) to skip existing tables and continue to create other tables rather than failing the schema creation. By default, the tables will have a schema prefix of “prod.”. When no option or ‘-help’ (‘-h’ for short) is provided, the command usage is printed. and continue to create other tables rather than failing the schema creation. When no option or ‘-help’ (‘-h’ for short) is provided, the command usage is printed. By default, the tables will have a schema prefix of “prod.”

but I cannot find code about TimelineSchemaCreator code in package org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.timelineservice.storage in any jar about Timeline server, why? is the document not update in time?

```
# find /opt/ -name 'hadoop-yarn-server-timelineservice*jar'
/opt/hadoop-3.1.1/share/hadoop/yarn/timelineservice/hadoop-yarn-server-timelineservice-3.1.1.jar
/opt/hadoop-3.1.1/share/hadoop/yarn/timelineservice/hadoop-yarn-server-timelineservice-hbase-common-3.1.1.jar
/opt/hadoop-3.1.1/share/hadoop/yarn/timelineservice/test/hadoop-yarn-server-timelineservice-hbase-tests-3.1.1.jar
/opt/hadoop-3.1.1/share/hadoop/yarn/timelineservice/hadoop-yarn-server-timelineservice-hbase-coprocessor-3.1.1.jar
/opt/hadoop-3.1.1/share/hadoop/yarn/timelineservice/hadoop-yarn-server-timelineservice-hbase-client-3.1.1.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

i find in hadoop-yarn-server-timelineservice-hbase-client-3.1.1.jar